# Permission to my .sh file?

Tags: permissions, sqldeveloper

H, I have been trying to install sqldeveloper in my newly installed ubuntu16.0.4 os.

The problem here is,I am not able edit my sqldeveloper.sh file. I tried with sudo, chmod and chown but it shows operation not permitted. Help me here.

```
harishaa@harishaa-system:/opt/sqldeveloper$ chown harishaa sqldeveloper.sh
chown: changing ownership of 'sqldeveloper.sh': Operation not permitted
```

This is the file I want to change:

```
harish@harish-system:/opt/sqldeveloper$ chown harish sqldeveloper.sh
chown: changing ownership of 'sqldeveloper.sh': Operation not permitted
```

Thank you.

Comment: Edit it as root,  e.g. using `sudo nano /opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't worry**, there is a quick and safe solution.

## How to execute an administrative action

### Very quick introduction to `sudo`

#### Single command line

In a terminal execute:

`sudo SUDOARGUMENTS COMMAND COMMANDARGUMENTS`

...after replacing:

- `SUDOARGUMENTS` with the parameters for the `sudo` utility (obtain a list from `sudo --help`;
- `COMMAND` with the command to execute as the administrative user (root);
- `COMMANDARGUMENTS` with the arguments for the command to execute as the administrative user (root).

#### Administrative session

Use only if necessary; always use the previous method if possible.

Execute `sudo su` to gain the root privileges and be very careful while executing any command.

Terminate the session using `exit` and **never leave a root interactive session active without control**.

### Example

If `sudo` is configured correctly you can execute your command with:

`sudo chown harishaa sqldeveloper.sh`

...it will ask the password of your current user and safely remember it for some minutes.
The command will be executed with higher privileges, **execute only commands from trusted sources**.

### Useful references

If you are the administrator of a multi-user system (for example a PC user by father, mother and two small kids) read the [official Ubuntu reference](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers#Introduction) for the configuration of `sudo`.

Feel free to comment under here if you need more support.